# Paypal Express Redirecting to Undefined

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3

I'm moving a site from craftcms/commerce-paypal to craft/commerce-paypal-checkout but I'm having an issue with the redirect after payment.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Choose Paypal as my gateway
2. I choose pay with Paypal
3. Paypal screen pops up
4. I make payment
5. I get redirected back to /store/undefined
6. Order is not completed in the backend - still in Active carts.

Everything looks to be rendering correctly on the frontend and the code works for the other gateways and the old Paypal, but the new Paypal gateway is redirecting to "undefined"

[image: Gateway-code]

[image: Rendered code]

[image: Redirected URL]

Is there something I need to do differently for the new Paypal gateway?